# Is there any native Windows 10 gpedit.msc patch for non-pro users?

Tags: windows, windows-10, gpedit

In *"native"* i mean the only solution i've found was [this](http://drudger.deviantart.com/art/Add-GPEDIT-msc-215792914), but its the WinXP gpedit.msc which somewhat run on Win7+.

Sometime ago i found a real Win10's gpedit but i forgot where i've got that.

Does anyone know if i wasnt dreaming and there's indeed a modern gpedit.msc floating around, or a alternative for this?

Comment: Do not download those files. You may find the file in WinSxS folder with dir /s command.

Comment: @Biswa That file is perfectly safe to use.

Comment: The Windows XP file has been confirmed to work on Windows 10. See my question/answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/q/1018145)

Comment: Not duplicate because i've asked specifically about a alternative to this gpedit

Comment: @Biswa I tried to run this gpedit but it says "mmc cannot open the file". I tried everything, even copy the file to System32

Comment: "Native" means "designed and intended for use in the specific context". In this context it means a gpedit meant for non-Pro versions of Win10. There is no such thing. So, the next closest thing is a version of the official program (MS-made) that will work on a non-Pro version of Win10. The WinXP version does work on non-Pro versions of Win10 as the duplicate question has noted. Perhaps clarifying why you want a "modern" gpedit might help us get you a better answer. Does the WinXP version have limited capability in some way?